# How DI in NestJS works?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

There is the following standard **NestJS** code:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Also there is the code for module app:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I don't understand how app understands that app controller expects to get app service as the first argument? At first I thought that app just looks at **providers** array and put all services from this array in controller's constructor. But I could change the code in this way:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, NewService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now I can use this **NewService** not only in **AppController** class, but in **AppService** class. How app knows that now I could use **NewService** in **AppService class**? Now I don't understand how we could do it, because **TypeScript** is just syntax sugar and exists only until compilation will be done and as I know app couldn't look at type of argument in **AppService** (for example **fileService: FileService**) and put the right service as argument when **AppService** will be created. I need technical details under the cover of this mechanism, not only use cases from official tutorial.

Comment: did you know about [`reflect-metadata`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata)? They use this API. You could see it [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/4b12f02f8c916e61a420841e7f0e3de0539961eb/packages/core/scanner.ts#L187)

Answer (score 0):

By registering it in the providers array you register it to the Nest IoC container.

If you check compiled js code, then you will find something like

```
WeatherHttpProvider = __decorate([
    (0, common_1.Injectable)(),
    __param(1, (0, common_1.Inject)(weather_parser_1.WEATHER_PARSER)),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [axios_1.HttpService, Object])
], WeatherHttpProvider);
```

which in this case tells the WeatherHttpProvider about injected constructor params. This way it knows which class from the IoC container to use.